# How I can check if user accepted permission for read/write Contacts?

Tags: android, permissions, screen, contacts

my app read contacts from cell phone so when it run he get for permission.

How I ask again or check if the user gave permission?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If the user downloaded the app then he accepted the permission. No need to check that.

Comment: If he installed your app he has no choice but to accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User's don't really have the option to chose which permissions they approve or not. It's either they approve everything and your app installs, or they chose to decline and then your app doesn't install.

However, to answer your question you can use the [checkPermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method in the PackageManager

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
int hasPermission = manager.checkPermission ("android.permission.READ_CONTACTS", "com.your.package")
if (hasPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //you have permission
}
```

Comment: another simple option:
int pid  = Process.myPid();
int uid  = Process.myUid();
int perm = checkPermission(permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, pid, uid);

Comment: However nowadays, more recently, since Android Marshmallow, the user has to accept permissions one by one even after installing the app.